# Popup not submitting form to itself - using magnific popup

Tags: php, jquery, magnific-popup

Trying to use `magnific popup` for a one page site and have the forms show as needed.

Calling the external file popup like so.

```
<a href="myformx.php" class="simple-ajax-iframe">form</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.simple-ajax-iframe').magnificPopup({
        type: 'iframe'
    });

    $('.simple-ajax-popup').magnificPopup({
        type: 'ajax'
    });

});
</script>

<form name="form1" method="POST" action="myformx.php">

<label>Your first name:</label>
<input class="formfield" name="your_name" type="text" value="" size="20">

<input class="submit" type="image" 
    id="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" 
    src="images/but_send.jpg" 
style="width: 97px; height: 51px;">
```

Form pops - awesome…
Form submission blanks out to nothing - not awesome.

Looking to determine how to get this to better submit to itself in the popup window.  Have tried several possibilities - none effectively.   Cant be that difficult - I'm missing the obvious here somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved.  Used this to manipulate and name the form out.  Note name="my_form".   Used target="my_form" on the form tag to get the post vars to submit to itself.   Hope this helps someone out.

```
$('.simple-ajax-iframe').magnificPopup({
    type: 'iframe',

    iframe: {
    markup: '<div class="mfp-iframe-scaler">'+
        '<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
        '<iframe class="mfp-iframe" name="myform" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>    </iframe>'+
      '</div>', // HTML markup of popup, `mfp-close` will be replaced by the close button
}
```